# Setting Up A High-Availability Load Balancer for Apache/Windows

Tags: windows, apache, load-balancing, tomcat7, high-availability

I'm currently trying to setup an environment where I have high availability even on the load-balancer. I have googled using multiple keywords, however all results that I got seemed to be tilted towards the LINUX/Debian world.

I'm on a windows environment, using Apache Server 2.2 with Tomcat 7. What I'm trying to get at is such that if a user visits my site and one of my load-balancer is down, I will still be able to serve my user.

As I'm a new user and will not be able to post photos, I've setup the photo at https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2k2E.jpg describing the network setup diagram. Thanks.

Appreciate any advice and sharings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your question is about. In every case every single load balancer should reach both webserver. Are your load balancers are appliances?

There's a possibility to configure Apache with mod_jk or mod_proxy as an load balancer too. But I'm not sure if your question is about that. Please precise.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good way to do this -- mod_spread looked like it would work, but those are really old bits.

On Windows, IIS can be configured for network load balancing such that a two-node system can present an "always-on" web page, but there simply doesn't appear to be an equivalent for Apache in Windows.

Edit: My mistake.  Network load balancing can balance **any** ports, not just IIS.  You need to set up a virtual IP for the pooled servers and add servers as members to the pool.

You still need some scripting to detect process failure as opposed to server failure.  Windows network load balancing won't detect failure of the individual network application, just the entire server.